# How to restore the most recent RDS Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a script that restores the most recent snapshot from RDS.

If I use this query it will get me the correct snapshot identifier.

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots  --db-instance-identifier test --query="reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime))[0]"
```

Is there a way to add the "DBSnapshotIdentifier" from this query to the
"aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot"
command for this to be executed in a single script?

Comment: Use shell command substitution. `aws rds restore-.... $(aws rds describe-....)`

Comment: Only issue is that aws rds describe gives me a lot of data. I need to see if there is a way to only get DBSnapshotIdentifier. Have your tried anyhting like this?

Comment: Use --output text and update your jq expression (the --query) to only return what you need

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get everything to work. I had to just rework the query to give me a better output.